# Instagram Profile Picture Access Denied

Tags: json, instagram, profile-picture

I get my client-id from instagram. It says 
`CLİENT STATUS  Live`
. But when I type this into browser it does not give me sample output in the website.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I replaced `ACCESS-TOKEN` with my client id. And I get this error.

```
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I wanna get this response.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "is_business": false,
    "counts": {
      "media": 1320,
      "follows": 420,
      "followed_by": 3410
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ACCESS-TOKEN` and `CLIENT ID` is not the same thing. You need to use your `CLIENT ID` to  retrieve an access token using OAuth: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication

Comment: Why I can not see other people information. I can only see my information. For instance when I type garyvee instead of self I want to see him information.

Comment: @neco Please look into this question, I am also getting the same issue

{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}